# touchUpInside and touchUpOutside of a button in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, touch-up-inside

LibGDX offers event listeners that we can attach to buttons. Inside listener there is a method `touchUp()` we can override. I come from iOS dev and in iOS there was an option `touchUpInside` and `touchUpOutside`. Namely, if the user released the finger inside the area of a button `touchUpInside` was called and if the user lifted finger outside the button area, `touchUpOutside` was called. Does libGDX offer similar functionality or is up to developers to implement that? The default libgdx `touchUp` does not differentiate these to scenarios.

edit: I used this code but this is extremely imprecise. I'm getting a lot of false touchUp's

```
public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            if(x<button.getX()||x>(button.getX()+button.getWidth())||y<button.getY()||y>(button.getY()+button.getHeight())){
                System.out.println("retuuurn");
                return;
            }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
if(x<button.getOriginX()-button.getWidth()*0.5f||x>(button.getOriginX()+button.getWidth()*0.5f)||y<button.getOriginY() - button.getHeight()*0.5f||y>(button.getOriginY()+button.getHeight()*0.5f)){
//do stuff
}
```